# Get html text-input element from django-form in template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

Given a `{{ form  }}` in a template for a model with a models.TextField called `text`, is there a way to access the html text-input field inside the same template directly from the form ?

I need something like `document.getElementById()` but don't know what id to pass.

Answer (score 0):

IDK what really you try to asking, explain more!

Comment: What I actually want, but didn't mention to not make it complicated, is be able to use the text currently contained in the textarea of my form's `text` field and pass it to a method, without submitting.